# aligning label with radio properly on line 2 html after css the label

Tags: html, css

I have a label with style

```
<input type="radio" id="testRadio" /><label for="testRadio">this is my label with multiple line text, and the align on this label is not working from second line. I want to start the text of second line from the same position as first line</label>

input {
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px !important;
}
```

as you can see the text on this label is in multiple lines, but the problem is when the text completed first line and started from 2nd line, the alignment is not proper,

here is [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zLgsm8wx/) for reference.

Comment: you can add     `display: inline-block;`

Comment: Please mark the answer accepted, if my solution resolved your issue.

Comment: No I updated my question please view the question again

Comment: Explain how `display:inline-block` for the label would not fix your problem then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the flex and then align parent items like this :

```css
.form-group {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; /* start or end */
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="radio" id="testRadio">
  <label for="testRadio">this is my label with multiple line text, and the align on this label is not working from second line. I want to start the text of second line from the same position as first line</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the label a **block** element to make it work.

```
display: block;
```

Update fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/k4gLp9uo/)

Comment: Updated my question for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Style the label **display:block** in your css

Comment: Updated my question for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would, as the first-posted answer suggests, be to use `display: block;`. However, because an alternative exists, I wanted to point out that the option of:

```
box-decoration-break: clone;
```

```css
label {
  margin-left: 10%;
  font-size: 24px;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  
}
```

```html
<label>this is my label with multiple line text, and the align on this label is not working from second line. I want to start the text of second line from the same position as first line</label>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gp9w0taL/).

But this *is* labelled as an 'experimental technology' on MDN (see the link in the references), so I would still advise using the easiest solution of `display: block`.

References:

- [`box-decoration-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-decoration-break).

Answer (score 0):

In your css you can simply set text-align: justify and this will sort it out.

```
label{
  margin-left:10%;
  font-size:24px;
  text-align: justify;
}
```